# Google Sheet Add-on get user email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Google Sheet add-on published in the store. But I can't get the user email back.

On Code.js, onStartup() when the app(sidebar) is loaded on the screen.

```
function onStartup() {
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

On my client side javascript, this is how I invoke onStartup().

```
google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(
          function(ret, scope) {
            console.log(">>> user email is: " + ret);
          })
        .withFailureHandler(
          function(msg, scope) {
          })
        .withUserObject()
        .onStartup();
```

EDIT:

Try getEffectiveUser() if you're working on an Add-on.

Comment: Is this code being run when your app first opens?  How do you know that `onStartup()` is running?  Put a `Logger.log('onStartup ran')` statement in your `onStartup()` function.  Is `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returning anything?  Are there any errors in the browser console when the app first loads?  Are there any error messages?  What are they?

Comment: Is the user clicking someting to run onStartup() or are you using the onOpen() trigger.   If you are using onOpen() then that runs in a restricted authorization and I believe UI is not an option.

Comment: @BjornBehrendt My client script will start onStartup() when the app(sidebar) is loaded on the screen. Do you think I can get email address anyway?

Comment: Hey men, I tested it on a sheet and it did not work directly - on sheet, it informs that there is an error about user access rights, but running the script on the script editor it launches a pop-up to inform that some privileges are required and ask user to accept. I think if this pop-up were launched from sheet, it would works, but how to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked in my test, it did initially give me some issues for an unknown reason:

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zevasz5XjumO92qOwYIvsqoUPkzyB9EBD27pWH2I5e0/copy

code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu().addItem('Launch Sidebar', 'sidebar').addToUi();
}

function sidebar(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Sidebar.html")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle("Sidebar Listbox");
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function getListItems(){
  var activeUser = "Active User";
  var effectiveUser = "Effective User";
  try{
    activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  } catch(err1){
    activeUser = err1;
  }
  try{
    effectiveUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  } catch(err2){
    effectiveUser = err2; 
  }
  var returnArray = [activeUser,effectiveUser]; 
  return returnArray;
}
```

Sidebar.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<p>
Effective User: <span id="effectiveUser"></span>
</p>
<p>
Active User: <span id="activeUser"></span>
</p>


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {    //This function runs automatically when the sidebar is opended  
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadListItems).withFailureHandler(fail).getListItems();
  });


    function loadListItems(returnedData){
    $( "#effectiveUser" ).html(returnedData[0]);
    $( "#activeUser" ).html(returnedData[1]);   
  }
     function fail(){
        //update the field with the id of yourChoice
      $( "#effectiveUser").html("<strong> Opps, something went wrong.... </strong>");
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Its interesting. I have to use getEffectiveUser(). getActiveUser() doesn't work for me. Maybe for adds-on, getActiveUser() doesn't work. But for regular script like yours, getActiveUser() is okay.

Comment: Here is the link I found about getActiveUser() might not work for Adds-on. https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/5D23Os_NIAc/WXn7-DMXYBEJ

Comment: I just looked at my code for my Connected Groups add-on and I see that I had to use getEffectiveUser

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser

> ...the user's email address is **not available** in any context that allows a
>   script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple
>   **onOpen(e)** or **onEdit(e) trigger**, a **custom function** in Google Sheets, or
>   a **web app** deployed to **"execute as me"** (that is, authorized by the
>   developer instead of the user)

`.getEffectiveUser()` is indeed the better option especially where custom functions are involved.